# How to convert datetime interval to hours?

Tags: google-sheets

I have this spreadsheet:

```
   A            B        C       D          E
1  08/13/2013   02:10    4                  
2  08/13/2013   02:19    10      00:09:00   160
```

In **D2**, I have this formula : `=if(B2="";"";to_date(concatenate(A2;" ";B2))-to_date(concatenate(A1;" ";B1)))`

In **E2** I have this formula : `=if(D2="";"";(C2-C1)/D2)`

But **E2** outputs the wrong result, 160. I want it to be 40 (=10-4/0.15). `0.15` is the value in **D2** converted to hours.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not quite understand what you're trying to calculate, but with the information that explains, the following formula can help:

```
=IF(D2 = "", "", ROUND((C2-C1)/(D2*24), 0))
```